# Add method to function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and am learning from the book *JavaScript: The Good Parts*. In that book, the following recipe is used to augment a method to all functions:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;
        return this;
    }
```

I wanted to explore this concept, so I came up with the following script, which aims to add the `greet()` method to the `func()` function:

```
//define how the augmentation will work
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
}

//create a dummy function to augment
function func() {
    //do nothing
}

//create function to be added
func.method('greet', function() {
    console.log("Greetings from greet()!");
});

//access the new function
func.greet();
```

When I run it, though, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s8aed1bx/

Comment: try `this[name]` instead of `this.prototype[name]`

Comment: @vp_arth That works, but I'd really like to know why. Could you explain or provide me a link I can read from? :)

Comment: @Phrogz already explained it :)

Comment: @vp_arth Yeah. I'm still don't understand it 100%, but it will help me look in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you want to modify the line:

```
this.prototype[name] = func;
```

to just

```
this[name] = func;
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s8aed1bx/1/

Alternatively you could use

```
this.constructor.prototype[name] = func;
```

but that would add each new method to every function, not just the one you call `method` on. Or you could use:

```
var f2 = new func();
f2.greet();
```

---

**Why?**

When looking up properties on an object in JavaScript, the object itself is searched, and then the `prototype` of the `constructor` of the object is searched (and so on up the chain). The `.constructor` of `func` is `Function`.

In this case what you have done would work if you wrote:

```
func.method('greet', function() {
  console.log("Greetings from greet()!");
});
var f2 = new func();
f2.greet();
```

The prototype of a function is used for new instances created by that function. (The objects you create have a `.constructor` of the creating function itself.)

Comment: Wow, thanks! If it's not too much of an effort, care to explain why? :)

Comment: Learn new thing today.

Comment: @dotslash Edited with more info.

Comment: @Phrogz Superb answer! Couldn't have asked for more. :)

Comment: @Manwal I guess it'd be the Function object which serves as the prototype for all functions? My JS fundamentals are quite shaky, though. :P